# How to use the conf file's filename from within an NGINX conf file?

Tags: nginx

If I have a file called `mysite.conf` stored in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.  Is there a way to get the string value `'mysite'` from within the conf file?

I want to symlink a common .conf file a bunch of times because they are all identical except for one little string.  As a quick example, instead of this:

```
server {
    #
    # snip
    #

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_error.log;

    #
    # snip
    #
}
```

I want to do this:

```
server {
    #
    # snip
    #

    access_log /var/log/nginx/$filename_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/$filename_error.log;

    #
    # snip
    #
}
```

I want to name the file `mysite.conf` and I want to symlink 5 more of them:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/mynextsite.conf
/etc/nginx/conf.d/myothersite.conf
etc
```

I want this so that I can re-use the exact same conf file for a few things.  I thought of this because I can do it with `uwsgi` using the `%n` variable.  It's handy not having to make a bunch of files all the time.  I just symlink them all to the same spot.  Can I do that with nginx conf files?

Comment: You can't refer to filename. But may be you don't need it, and could refer to domain instead?

Comment: domain might work.  How do you refer to it?

Comment: Would be a great feature. I also have some configurations that are always the same. With this method I could simply link the files together...

Comment: @RamondeKlein Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one server block for it. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    sever_name example.com example.org domain.net;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/${host}_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/${host}_access.log;

    ....
}
```

So files would be named `/var/log/nginx/example.org_access.log` or `/var/log/nginx/domain.net_access.log`.

Comment: it doesn't work! how can we use variable in the access_file filename?

Comment: @MasoudJahromi ask another question and show your config file there